# chrome extension http request to website

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome-extension

I wanted to make a chrome extension that gets the html code from this website:  https://free-proxy-list.net/ 
without actually going to that webpage.

I tried using the steps here: 
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr
but the request kept showing as undefined when I tried to print it out.

The script I was using was:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
}
xhr.open('GET', "url", true);
xhr.send(null);

document.write(xhr.send());
```

Note: not putting url in code since SO won't let me post a question with more than 2 links.

How would I get the code from this website in a string variable that I can parse?

Comment: the `send()` function does not return the response, you have to move `document.write` into the `onreadystatechange` function

Comment: I added the line: document.write(xhr.responseText); after the alert statement, but nothing shows up still. It doesn't show undefined anymore though.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log

Comment: The document is not opened for writing in your callback. Why are you using it instead of proper DOM manipulation?

Comment: Where should I put the document.write then?